# Safely insert row data from one table to another - SQL

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, transactions

I need to move some data stored in one table to another using a script, taking into account existing records that may already be in the destination table as well as any relationships that may exist.

I am curious to know the best method of doing this that has a relatively low impact on performance and can be reversed if necessary.

At first I will be moving only one record to ensure the process runs smoothly but then it will be responsible for moving around 1650 rows.

What would be the best approach to take or is there a better alternative?

Edit:

My previous suggestion of using MERGE will not work as I will be operating under the SQL Server 2005 environment, not 2008 like previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the question does not provide any details, so I can't provide any *actual real* code, just this plan of attack:

**step 1** write a query that will SELECT only the rows you need to copy.  You will need to `JOIN` and/or filter (`WHERE`) this data to only include the rows that don't already exist in the destination table.  Make the column list be the exact same as the destination table's columns, in column order and data type.

**step 2** turn that SELECT statement into an INSERT by adding `INSERT YourDestinationTable (col1, col2, col3..)` before the select.

**step 3** if you only want to try a single row, add a `TOP 1` to the select part of the new `INSERET - SELECT command`, you can rerun this command as many times as necessary with/without a `TOP` because it should eliminate any rows you add by the `JOIN`s and `WHERE` conditions in the `SELECT`

in the end, you'll have something that looks like:

```
INSERT YourDestinationTable
        (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
    SELECT
        s.Col1, s.Col2, s.Col3, ...
        FROM YourSourceTable                s
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeOtherTable  x ON s.Col4=x.Col4
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourDestinationTable d WHERE s.PK=d.PK)
            AND x.Col5='J'
```

I'm reading the question as only inserting missing rows from a source table to a destination table.  If changes need to be migrated as well then prior to the above steps you will need to do an `UPDATE` of the destination table joining in the source table.  This is hard to explain without more specifics of the actual tables, columns, etc.

Comment: To answer your question I will only be inserting rows that don't already exist, there will be no need to update anything using a similar method afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MERGE statement is ideal for bulk imports if you are running SQL Server 2008.